# Django error:name '_' is not defined,when I try to create a new model

Tags: python

I Defined this model

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CharField
# Create your models here.
class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('state.State',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('City Name'))

    def __unicode__(self, ):
        return str(self.city_name)
```

But when I want to use it I get this error
in City

```
city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('City Name'))
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

I dont know where the problem is

Comment: Did you import `_`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to import the gettex or alternative function `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _`. Take a look at [django i18n documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/)